# spring security + oauth2 + Reactjs + zuul proxy

Tags: spring, security, oauth-2.0, netflix-zuul

I am working with oauth2 and spring security and using zuul proxy. I have a login button in client web app. When a user clicks on it the request should redirect to authentication server for authentication. but it's not redirecting the request to the authentication server. I am sharing my code, kindly give some solution.

**1. Client web application code**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableZuulProxy
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class OauthUiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(OauthUiApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Configuration
    protected static class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.logout().and().antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/index.html", "/home.html", "/", "/login").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated().and().csrf()
                    .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository()).and()
                    .addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
        }

        private Filter csrfHeaderFilter() {
            return new OncePerRequestFilter() {
                @Override
                protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                        HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
                        throws ServletException, IOException {
                    CsrfToken csrf = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class
                            .getName());
                    if (csrf != null) {
                        Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, "XSRF-TOKEN");
                        String token = csrf.getToken();
                        if (cookie == null || token != null
                                && !token.equals(cookie.getValue())) {
                            cookie = new Cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", token);
                            cookie.setPath("/");
                            response.addCookie(cookie);
                        }
                    }
                    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
                }
            };
        }

        private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
            HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
            repository.setHeaderName("X-Csrf-Token");
            return repository;
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleFilter simpleFilter() {
        return new SimpleFilter();
    }

}
```

**2. application.yml file**

```
debug:
zuul:
  routes:
    resource:
      path: /resource/**  # we are proxying to resource server 'resource'
      url: http://localhost:9000/resource # All the requests that starts with /resource/ will be routed to this URL
    user:
      path: /user/**  # proxying to user end point on the authorization server
      url: http://localhost:9999/uaa/user # All the requests that starts with /user/ will be routed to this URL
security:
  user:
    password: none
  oauth2:
    sso:
      login-path: /login
    client:
      accessTokenUri: http://localhost:9999/uaa/oauth/token # token endpoint
      userAuthorizationUri: http://localhost:9999/uaa/oauth/authorize # authrization end point
      clientId: acme # client id
      clientSecret: acmesecret # client secret id
    resource:
      jwt:
        keyValue: |
          -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
          MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAgnBn+WU3i6KarB6gYlg40ckBiWmtVEpYkggvHxow74T19oDyO2VRqyY9oaJ/cvnlsZgTOYAUjTECjL8Ww7F7NJZpxMPFviqbx/ZeIEoOvd7DOqK3P5RBtLsV5A8tjtfqYw/Th4YEmzY/XkxjHH+KMyhmkPO+/tp3eGmcMDJgH+LwA6yhDgCI4ztLqJYY73gX0pEDTPwVmo6g1+MW8x6Ctry3AWBZyULGt+I82xv+snqEriF4uzO6CP2ixPCnMfF1k4dqnRZ/V98hnSLclfMkchEnfKYg1CWgD+oCJo+kBuCiMqmeQBFFw908OyFKxL7Yw0KEkkySxpa4Ndu978yxEwIDAQAB
          -----END PUBLIC KEY-----
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.security: DEBUG


3.
```

Comment: the code does not look like it is related to reactjs at all

Comment: I have not copied react code here.

Comment: You are expected to provide a MCVE https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve